# Convert the String to Big Decimal with format ("##,##0.00") in Jasperreport

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I would like to convert the field from String to Big Decimal with Format ("##,##0.00") in Java.
Previously, we got the DataSource from sql, but for now using csv as datasource. it mean all of the fields is using string format.
****Note****
-GRP_FAC_ACT_BAL: String

Syntax: $F{GRP_FAC_ACT_BAL}==null?"":new DecimalFormat("##,##0.00").format($F{GRP_FAC_ACT_BAL})

Comment: @AlexK are you sure that is the correct duplicate? The linked question does not handle a format like asked here

Comment: Hi AlexK, I don't know why my question go to duplicate. Could you kindly to response my query above?